How to compute probability of event E happening and having K occurences of E within the last M trials
When sampled within a time of N trial successive events, I know the probability of success P of an event E. This probability P of event E is constant and doesn’t change with each sampling trial. I know I can use the binomial distribution to compute the probability of event E happening K or more times over M trials.
I want to compute the probability of picking E for a trial and having at least K event E happening within the last M trials including the current trial.
I believe to compute this probability I need to use the binomial distribution and compute the probability of a trial having a probability of success P being successful at least K-1 times out of M-1 trials. Then multiply the computed binomial probability output by the probability P of event E.
I am right?
